# Can't swipe to scroll page over primefaces carousel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using **primefaces carousel** to navigate through a list of items via swipe left/right on a mobile web page.

But swipe up/down to scroll page doesn't work over the carousel.

How can I achieve to have both, carousel navigation with swipe left/rigth and page scrolling with swipe up/down? (like in Primefaces Showcase)

I'm using **Primefaces 5.3**. (I have also tried Primefaces 6.1)

Comment: Start by trying PrimeFaces 6.1 or 6.2-SNAPSHOT to see if it by chance is fixed in a newer release (always do this). In addition you can (should) also check the commits and releasenotes. If it is not solved in these, you can download the source to see if you can create a patch (and file a pull request) and if that does not work, you can file an enhancement request in their github

Comment: I've updatet to PrimeFaces 6.1 but it doesn't fixed this issue. On Primefaces Showcase I have no problems with carousel and page scrolling on mobile device.

Comment: Hi TopicStarter, Can you update us on the status?